# Dynamo DB export through UI

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Require your help please.

I have entered a query in Dynamo DB and have received 200000 rows. When I click on export to csv option in UI i only get 100 rows. I have seen setting to change this to 300 rows also. But I want to know is there any way through which all the above rows are exported at one go through UI option.

Answer (score 0):

Ive used [DynamoDBtoCSV](https://github.com/edasque/DynamoDBtoCSV),very handy and simple

1. clone repo
2. run `npm install` inside the folder
3. update config.json with your AWS credentials
4. run `node dynamoDBtoCSV.js -t your_table > output.csv`

hope be helpful